# INSERT statement for AutoNumber field text box (Access)

Tags: c#, ms-access, auto-increment, windows-forms-designer, autonumber

I have a Windows form which has the following textboxes, and is displayed in gridview. The application is connected to an Access database using C#.

Companyid (autonumber)
CompanyName(shorttext)
TypeofCompany(shorttext)

How can I generate an AutoNumber field to update itself with an INSERT statement?

e.g., C001,C002,C003,C004.....

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Shrenik_Salguna\Desktop\final.accdb;
        Persist Security Info=False;");
        con.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO info
                     ([Name of Company], [Type of Company]) VALUES('"+textBox1.Text+"','" + textBox2.Text + ")", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

If [Companyid] is an `AutoNumber` field in the Access table then you don't include that field in your INSERT statement because the Access Database Engine takes care of that for you.

You could conceivably create *your own* "auto-increment" field containing "C001", "C002", etc., but if you already have a true `AutoNumber` field then why would you bother? You already have a unique column for each row on the table, and if you wanted to derive an identifier like "Cnnn" then you could easily do that in C# by just using something equivalent to this VBA expression:

```
"C" & Format([Companyid], "000")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I created a table with an **autoNumber** field:

```
        ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
        ADOX.Table table = new ADOX.Table();
        ADOX.Key tableKey = new Key();
        ADOX.Column col = new Column();

        String SecurityDBConnection = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}\\{1};", value, SecurityDBName);

        // Define column with AutoIncrement features
        col.Name = "ID";
        col.Type = ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger;


        // Define security table
        table.Name = "Security";
        table.Columns.Append(col);    // default data type is text[255]
        table.Columns.Append("Username", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 255);
        table.Columns.Append("Password", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 255);
        table.Columns.Append("Engineer", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adBoolean);
        table.Columns.Append("Default", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adBoolean);

        tableKey.Name = "Primary Key";
        tableKey.Columns.Append("ID");
        tableKey.Type = KeyTypeEnum.adKeyPrimary;

        // Add security table to database
        cat.Create(SecurityDBConnection);

        // Must create database file before applying autonumber to column
        col.ParentCatalog = cat;
        col.Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = true;

        cat.Tables.Append(table);

        // Now, try to connect to cfg file to verify that it was created successfully
        ADODB.Connection con = cat.ActiveConnection as ADODB.Connection;
        if (con != null) con.Close();
```

Here is the code to insert a record into the table with an **autoNumber** field.  Note, the autoNumber field is **NOT** specified in the insert statement and the field names are bracketed.

```
        public void WriteRecord(String sUsername, String sPassword, Boolean boEngineerRole, Boolean boDefaultUser)
       {
        String InsertQry = "Insert into Security([Username], [Password], [Engineer], [Default]) "
            + "values(@UserName, @Password, @Engineer, @Default)";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(SecurityDBConnection))
        {
           using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(InsertQry, connection))
           {
               command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", sUsername);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", sPassword);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Engineer", boEngineerRole);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DefaultUser", boDefaultUser);
               connection.Open();
               command.ExecuteNonQuery();
           }
        }
    }
```